# Mysql sum of count distinct grouped by month

Tags: mysql

Have really sticky issue at hand.
How do i count the total of users provided by this.

```
SELECT 
MONTH(VisitTime) AS mon, 
COUNT( distinct IP) AS usersbymonth
FROM stats 
WHERE 
YEAR( VisitTime) = YEAR(  current_date  )  
GROUP BY mon
```

the tricky par is, that the rollup and count(distinct IP) provides lower
count (distinct in whole year). Thats because the GROUP BY mon allows same IP to exists in multible months.

Now the result shows the basics right. Month number|usersbymonth and if you do the query targeted last year, its gonna result 12 months with users pre month.

So how i can count the usersbymonth cells sum?

Comment: so if you have user X coming in from an IP in both January and March, you only want that to count as 1 visit, where your current query counts that as 2 different visits? you'd have to do a separate query and group by year instead, since the per-month grouping destroys any chance of doing a distinct on those "different" visits.

Comment: the basic query shown do everything as i want it to. User visiting march and january is counted as 2. i only want to count the total sum of all the months together so i can count % of users in month

Answer (score 2):

Am i right ?

```
SELECT mon, SUM(usersbymonth) FROM 
  (SELECT 
  MONTH(VisitTime) AS mon, 
  COUNT( distinct IP) AS usersbymonth
  FROM stats 
  WHERE 
  YEAR( VisitTime) = YEAR(  current_date  )  
  GROUP BY mon)
```

If you want for each month just add `GROUP BY mon`
   **UPDATE**

```
  SELECT 
      MONTH(VisitTime) AS mon, 
      COUNT( distinct IP) AS usersbymonth
  FROM stats 
  WHERE 
      YEAR( VisitTime) = YEAR(  current_date  )  
  GROUP BY mon
  UNION -- Last ROW
  SELECT mon, SUM(usersbymonth) FROM (
    SELECT 
      MONTH(VisitTime) AS mon, 
      COUNT( distinct IP) AS usersbymonth
    FROM stats 
    WHERE 
      YEAR( VisitTime) = YEAR(  current_date  )  
    GROUP BY mon)
```

Comment: basicly yes. results are ok but.. the second does just what mine does only in more complex way. first results just the number that im looking for, but i just want the total to be the 13th line or an extra col in every row in one query

Comment: you mean you want total result at the last row yeap ?

Comment: yeap. like this. jan 50, feb 50, mar 50 etc total 150 and still distinct by month

Comment: so the sum(usersbymonth) would provide the right anwer.. but how the he** i implement it to the query :)

Comment: Thanks molderf. works fine now but needs some re thinking cause its a damn slow query.

Comment: distinct IP this is **IP adress** from _stats_ ? or what is it ?

Comment: yep. contains the visitors ip